# Right arrow in carousel not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working through this tutorial and I have everything working as expected except for the right arrow in the carousel is not appearing. I dont understand what could be the issue b/c the left one is appearing just fine. Here is my code below.

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

    @* Carosuel Indicate which you can click on*@

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class ="item active">
            <img src="~/Images/beach.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Beach</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Images/elepahant.JPG" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Images/jaguar.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Images/valley.JPG" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Works here copied and pasted; http://www.bootply.com/VmtXdXpew5

Answer (score 0):

Found out I was doing everything right. One of the pictures had a lot of white space that I didn't notice causing the right arrow to be push over, which I didn't see. Thanks for all who responded.